# How to implement Basic Auth using Karate?

Tags: karate

I saw details about OAuth2 in Karate Demo. Can you also provide how to implement Basic Auth?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, this JS function is all you need (`basic-auth.js`):

```
function(creds) {
  var temp = creds.username + ':' + creds.password;
  var Base64 = Java.type('java.util.Base64');
  var encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(temp.getBytes());
  return 'Basic ' + encoded;
}
```

And then use this function to build the value of the `Authorization` header:

```
* header Authorization = call read('basic-auth.js') { username: 'john', password: 'secret' }
```

Refer to the docs here: https://github.com/intuit/karate#http-basic-authentication-example

For OAuth or "login form" kinds of flows, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58643689/143475 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/46333729/143475

Comment: This function was a great help, but it didn't work for me for some reason.

I had to modify this line:

`var encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(temp.bytes);`

to: 

`var encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(temp.getBytes());`

Comment: @PeteLoggie thanks, I edited the answer. this happened when we changed the JS engine in 1.X: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide#javabean-property-short-cuts-dont-work-in-all-cases

Comment: Sry but what’s creds in above?