# karate how to authenticate with awscognito userpool?

Tags: graphql, amazon-cognito, karate, aws-appsync

I am learning karate and want to authenticate cognito userpool like this
the url im using here take me to login page if posted in browser.

```
 Scenario:   user Auth
        Given url   'https://mynewdomasdinhai.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/login?client_id=7s5jhgjhv4n&response_type=code&scope=email+openid&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8000/dashboard'     
        And header Content-Type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'
        And form field grant_type = 'password'
        And form field password = 'xuxxx'
        And form field username = 'alisd'
        When method post
        Then status 200
        * print response
```

im totally lost here could someone help me how to improve this code.

Comment: a lot depends on the specific auth flow. you may have to do some research. refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51246220/143475 - and please do post your findings back to help others