# How to setup oauth 1.0 authentication with karate for twitter?

Tags: oauth, twitter-oauth, karate

I am using karate for automation and I have to use oauth 1.0 authentication which has 4 fields that are token, tokensecret, consumerkey, and consumersecret. I could not do it with karate. Could you please help me on this issue?

I hhave tried to implement something using configure header options, however it was not successful. I am not experienced with karate, I could not try anything else.

This is how I made it work with rest assured. I want to implement same logic with karate. Below is the code for rest assured;

'''
    Response response = given().auth().oauth(consumerKey, 
    consumerSecret, token, tokenSceret).
                queryParam("screen_name", "realDonaldTrump").
                queryParam("count", 1).
                when().get("/user_timeline.json").
                then().extract().response();
'''

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the demos: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo

And look at the [OAuth1 example](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/oauth/oauth1.feature).

It requires you to do Java Interop: https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-java

So unless you are prepared to write [one Java class](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/oauth/Signer.java) and use it from Karate, you can choose to look for another framework.

And you need to refer to the Twitter API also if needed: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/creating-a-signature

This is not built into Karate as it can get very specifc. Please take the help of someone who knows Java etc. if needed, all the best.

```
* def Signer = Java.type('com.myco.Signer')    
* def params =
"""
{ 
  'userId': '399645532', 
  'os':'android', 
  'client_key': '3c2cd3f3',
  'token': '141a649988c946ae9b5356049c316c5d-838424771',
  'token_client_salt': 'd340a54c43d5642e21289f7ede858995'
}
"""
* Signer.sign('382700b563f4', params)
* path 'echo'
* form fields params
* method post
* status 200
```